# UPnP port mapping client for Linux

Tags: port-forwarding, nat, upnp

Is there any client that can request mapping and unmapping ports via UPnP port mapping behind a NAT gateway?
I had problem with [PortMap](http://upnp-portmapper.sourceforge.net/). I want this mostly for testing purposes.

Comment: It should be noted that many sysadmins disable UPnP on their routers because of a long history of security vulnerabilities in both implementation and design.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `upnpc` from [MiniUPnP](http://miniupnp.free.fr/).

For gateways supporting the NAT-PMP protocol, `natpmpc` is available from the [same site](http://miniupnp.free.fr/libnatpmp.html).

Answer (score 10):

Complementing @user1686 answer. This is how you can do it on Ubuntu, Mint and all Debian based distros:

```
# Install upnpc command line
sudo apt install -y miniupnpc

# Get network ip address (typically started with 192)
export IP=$(hostname -I | tr " " "\n" | grep 192)

# External port 2222 forwarded to internal port 22
upnpc -e "upnpc test" -a $IP 22 2222 TCP

# Delete
upnpc -d 2222 TCP
```

Comment: And if you use a firewall, you have to enable UDP packets coming from the router. In my case, I use `ufw`, so the command would be something like this `sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.1 to any proto udp`

Answer (score 3):

I found [upnp-router-control](https://launchpad.net/upnp-router-control) that make it possible to do it with a beautiful GUI interface.